# Magento Cart:Checking if the items in cart are reordered items

Tags: php, magento

It is possible to check if the items  in the cart are reordered items or not.When the store is changed by the customers the cart items of previous store is removed. When the reorder is done from the user area, I have redirected to the respective stores from where the items was purchased.So  the problem is that, the reordered items are also removed from the cart when I redirect it to original store from where it was bought.Is there any solution to check if the items of the cart are reordered and not deleting those items.  I am using magento 1.7
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the customer is log in. On the view my cart page you could lookup there order history and compare it their current cart items.